# Cannot access ng-if parent's scope

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="goal in goals">
    {{ goal }}
    {{ goal.bodyGoalId }}
</div>
```

this outputs goal and bodyGoalId as expected

with the following however

```
<div ng-repeat="goal in goals">
    <div ng-if="goal.bodyGoalId !== null">
        {{ goal.bodyGoalId }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The if div is created and if the condition is reversed it is not created.  no matter what I do to try and output the bodyGoalId however nothing is output.  I imagine this has something to do with the new scope created by the ng-if but I thought the ng-if inherited its parents scope but I must not understand it correctly.

What is the correct way to get this working?

edit1:

So the above dosn't work with ng-show so it must not be a scope problem.  Here is the actual code followed by the object I am trying to access. please not that %% %% is equivilant to {{ }} in this code

```
<table class="col-xs-12 table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

    <tr>

        <th scope="col" class=""><h4>Created</h4></th>
        <th scope="col" class=""><h4>Type</h4></th>
        <th scope="col" class=""><h4>Targets</h4></th>

    </tr>

    <div ng-repeat="goal in goals">

        <tr ng-show="goal.distanceGoalId !== null">
            <th>%% goal.distanceGoalId %%</th>
            <th>Distance</th>

            <th>
                Excersise: %% goal.distance_goal_desc.excersise.name %%</br>
                Distance: %% goal.distance_goal_desc.distance %%</br>
                Time: %% goal.distance_goal_desc.time %%
            </th>
        </tr>
   </div>
</table>
```

and the %% goal %% object ouput

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "userId":"1",
    "title":"first goal title",
    "goalDesc":"This should describe my goal in text form",
    "goalStatus":"0",
    "bodyGoalId":null,
    "strengthGoalId":null,
    "distanceGoalId":"1",
    "created_at":"2014-01-24 12:11:40",
    "updated_at":"2014-01-24 12:11:40",
    "body_goal_desc":null,
    "distance_goal_desc":
        {"id":"1","excersise":
            {"id":"1","name":"Leg Extension",
                "type":"Resistance",
                "variation":null,
                "equipment":"Machine",
                "focus":"Legs",
                "desc":"",
                "video":null,
                "created_at":"2014-01-24 12:11:41",
                "updated_at":"2014-01-24 12:11:41"
             },
         "distance":"9.50",
         "time":"01:22:00",
         "created_at":"2014-01-24 12:11:40",
         "updated_at":"2014-01-24 12:11:40"
        },
     "strength_goal_desc":null}
```

controller

```
myApp.controller('goalCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.goals = null;

    $scope.getGoals = function (userid) {
        $http.get('/goals/' + userid).success(function (goals, status) {
            if (!isEmpty(goals)) {
                $scope.goals = goals;
            };
        });
    };
}]);
```

edit 2: if I remove the ng-repeat div from the table the values are displayed as normal

Comment: You've forgot to close the first tag

Comment: thanks that was just a type in the question, not in the actual code

Comment: I would use `ng-show` `<div ng-show="goal.bodyGoalId !== null">`

Comment: nothing wrong with your code see: http://jsfiddle.net/bUpP7/1/

Comment: Thank you, I just checked it with ng-show and have the same problem so it shouldn't be scope it must be how I am accessing the properties, I will update my question

Comment: If you're still struggling, could you please post your controller code?

Comment: I just updated with more info I will add the controller now but it is just a simple http.get and I can see the correct object with %% goal %% in the ng-repeat so I don't think it has to do with the controller

Comment: i dont really understand your question at all. it works fine here.

Comment: it works dude http://jsfiddle.net/bUpP7/2/

Comment: It has something to do with the divs in the table element when I changed the ng-repeat to a tr instead of a div and the ng-if to each individual th element instead of grouping the ths in a div it works